# Wordpress add link on slider php

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

i have a problem to add link to whole slider.
code that is in theme is like this. i add a href and esc_url( $this->_var( 'button_link' ) ) but when slider generates it is like this `<a></a><div></div>` and it should be like this `<a><div></div></a>`

```js
$output = sprintf(
   '<a href="%13$s"><div class="tm_pb_slide%6$s"%4$s%10$s%11$s>
    %8$s
    %12$s
    <div class="tm_pb_container clearfix">
     %5$s
     <div class="tm_pb_slide_description">
      %1$s
      <div class="tm_pb_slide_content%9$s">%2$s</div>
      %3$s
     </div> <!-- .tm_pb_slide_description -->
    </div> <!-- .tm_pb_container -->
    %7$s
   </div></a> <!-- .tm_pb_slide -->
   ',
   $this->_var( 'heading' ),
   $this->shortcode_content,
   $this->_var( 'button' ),
   $this->_var( 'style' ),
   $this->_var( 'image' ),
   esc_attr( $class ),
   ( '' !== $this->_var( 'background_video' ) ? $this->_var( 'background_video' ) : '' ),
   ( '' !== $this->_var( 'background_image' ) && 'on' === $tm_pb_slider_parallax ? sprintf( '<div class="tm_parallax_bg%2$s" style="background-image: url(%1$s);"></div>', esc_attr( $this->_var( 'background_image' ) ),
   ( 'off' === $tm_pb_slider_parallax_method ? ' tm_pb_parallax_css' : '' ) ) : '' ),
   ( 'on' === $tm_pb_slider_hide_mobile['hide_content_on_mobile'] ? esc_attr( " {$hide_on_mobile_class}" ) : '' ),
   $data_dot_nav_custom_color,
   $data_arrows_custom_color,
   'on' === $this->_var( 'use_bg_overlay' ) ? '<div class="tm_pb_slide_overlay_container"></div>' : '',
   esc_url( $this->_var( 'button_link' ) )
  );
```

Code in frontend

```html
<p>
<a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/"></a></p>
    <div class="tm_pb_slide tm_pb_bg_layout_light tm_pb_media_alignment_center tm_pb_slide_0 tm-pb-active-slide" style="background-color:#ffffff;background-image:url(https://blog.modile.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/aksamitne-botki-fashion-week-fot-imaxtree.jpg);"><a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/">
    
    
    </a><div class="tm_pb_container clearfix" style="min-height: 655px;"><a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/">
     
     </a><div class="tm_pb_slide_description"><a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/">
      </a><h2 class="tm_pb_slide_title"><a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/"></a><a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/">Jakie botki są modne jesienią 2016?</a></h2>
      <div class="tm_pb_slide_content">
<p style="text-align: left;">Na jesień 2016 projektanci przygotowali różnorodne botki. Sprawdź, czy wśród najmodniejszych fasonów, jest model dla ciebie.</p>
</div>
      <a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/" class="tm_pb_more_button tm_pb_button">Czytaj więcej</a>
     </div> <!-- .tm_pb_slide_description -->
    </div> <!-- .tm_pb_container -->
    
   </div>
```

Comment: Is the link not showing up at all, or is it not displaying correctly?

Comment: @stack-flo i add frontend code to post so you can see what its looks like

Comment: @stack-flo as you can see <a href="https://blog.modile.pl/2016/10/26/jaki-botki-sa-modne-jesienia-2016/"> is added multiple times